# Endless redirect with basic auth in sub-folder and all requests rewritten to index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, basic-authentication

I have a site running on Apache that has all requested rewritten to index.php, except for requests to /login/*. The login directory is protected by basic auth and an .htpasswd file.

My root .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/.*$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And the .htaccess file in /login/ looks like this:

```
AuthName "Please enter your username and password."
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

When I attempt to goto the /login/ directory I get an endless loop of redirects to /login/. If I remove the all three rewrite lines in the root .htaccess I finally get a basic auth prompt in /login/.

What do I need to do to prevent the endless redirect?